# xss: is it possible to continue javascript code execution after a "throw new Error()" line?

Tags: xss, javascript

there is this javascript file that a can inject code after `throw new Error("error string")` line. But it seems that after the throw statement, no code can be executed.

```
throw new Error("error string");
<my xss code here>
```

if there was no semicolon at the end of the statement I think it would possible to run code by a conditional(ternary) operator like this:

```
throw new Error("error string")
? 1==0: code
```

Is there any way to run code after the throw statement? maybe an undocumented way?

Comment: you can continue only if you catch it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't catch because I only control the code after the throw new error line and the is no "try" before it so I would include a catch

Comment: maybe try with window. onerror()

Comment: This is a pure programming question. I suggest to move it to SO.

Comment: window.onerror don't seems to work, i'll move this question to programming

Comment: `setTimeout("alert(123)");throw 666;`

Comment: `try {
  throw new Error("error string");
} catch (error) {
  console.error("This: "+error);
}`  https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of unexpected corners of the language that could change the control flow. There may be new ones added in future versions of JavaScript To be safe, I would always assume that allowing to inject code anywhere is potentially a vulnerability.

For your particular example, it is enough to change the Error constructor through a locally hoisted definition. The code below will output “XSS” to the console.

```
throw new Error("error string");
function Error() { console.log('XSS'); }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're really injecting inside a javascript file then I can't see a way to continue execution. If you're injecting inside a script tag in an html document, then you can close the script tag and open a new one, which will be executed independently.

Comment: The injection point is inside a javascript file, maybe I should move on and look for bugs elsewhere, thanks.